# How to have a nested inline formset within a form in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-forms

I hope this question has not been asked yet, but I want to know if it is possible to have a normal class-based form for an object and to have an inline formset inside it to edit its related objects.

For example, I have a Contact model

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    ...
```

And a Communication model

```
class Communication(models.Model):
   contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
```

and I want to have a form for Contact with a inline formset nested in it for managing communications related to it.

Is it possible to do so with existing components or do I have a hopeless dream?

EDIT : I know that the admin panel does it, but how do I make work in a view?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Of course it's possible - how do you think the admin does it?

Take a look at the [inline formsets documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

**Edited after comment** Of course, you need to instantiate and render both the parent form and the nested formset. Something like:

```
def edit_contact(request, contact_pk=None):
    if contact_pk:
        my_contact = Contact.objects.get(pk=contact_pk)
    else:
        my_contact = Contact()
    CommunicationFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Contact, Communication)
    if request.POST:
        contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST, instance=my_contact)
        communication_set = CommunicationFormSet(request.POST,
                                                 instance=my_contact)
        if contact_form.is_valid() and communication_set.is_valid():
            contact_form.save()
            communication_set.save()
    else:
        contact_form = ContactForm(instance=my_contact)
        communication_set = CommunicationFormSet(instance=my_contact)
 
    return render_to_response('my_template.html', 
                              {'form': contact_form, 'formset':communication_set})
```

and the template can be as simple as:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {{ formset }}
</form>
```

although you'll probably want to be a bit more detailed in how you render it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I tried it and when I render the formset, there are only lines for the related objects. I need the Contact form AND the Communication Inline formset. I know that the admin panel does it, but how do I make work in a view?

Comment: is there any way to add the formset into the main form? for some reasons I can have a single modelform only and I need a inlineformset inside it.

Comment: The link to 'inline formsets documentation' produces a 404 error